# decode response data to convert special symbols

Tags: ios, objective-c, encoding, nsstring, utf8-decode

Decode the special symbols like html tags $ @

response jsonString

```
"value": "15000",
"price": "\u20b9125.00\/-",
"href": "http:\/\/abce\/abcd\/index.php?route=abcd\/product&amp;id=abcd"
```

// Converting price into $ I am using below code, but decodedString is showing nil.

```
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSData *unicodedStringData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *decodedString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:unicodedStringData encoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
```

I got response data, after decode its give an nil value.
Can any one advice me to resolved the issue.

@All Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code.

```
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:urlData        encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSData *unicodedStringData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSString *decodedString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:unicodedStringData encoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
```

Edited, Try below code,

```
NSString *decodedString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:unicodedStringData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

Regards,

Amit